# Unable to save with LINQ when trying to insert record with foreign keys?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I havent been able to find anything on this online. I've got a `ReservationDate` model,

```
namespace Mijem_test_app.Models
{
    [HandleError]
 /*
     This model includes the location,
     the person who reserved it and
     FOR when they reserved it (not
     when they reserved it)
*/
    public class ReservationDate
    {
        //key
        public int Id { get; set; }

        //location name
        [Required]
        public Reservation Reservation { get; set; }

        //contact
        [Required]
        public Contact Contact { get; set; }

        //date reserved for
        [Required]
        public DateTime ReservedDate { get; set; }

        //information from textbox
        [Required]
        public string InfoFromTextBox { get; set; }

        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        public ImagesUploaded ImageURL { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in my controller, I try to `CREATE` a record,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(ReservationDate reservation)
{
    var _contactID = (int) TempData["ContactID"];

    var _contact = _context.Contacts
        .Single(r => r.Id == _contactID);

    var _location = _context.Reservations
        .Single(r => r.Name == reservation.Reservation.Name);

    var _ReservedDate = (DateTime)TempData["BookDate"];

    var _InfoFromTextBox = (string)TempData["InfoFromTextBox"];

    var __reservation = new ReservationDate
    {
        ReservedDate = _ReservedDate,
        Contact = _contact.Id,
        Reservation = _location.Id,
        InfoFromTextBox = _InfoFromTextBox,
        Deleted = false
    };

    _context.ReservationDates.Add(__reservation);

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return View("Index");
}
```

The code breaks at

```
    Contact = _contact.Id,
    Reservation = _location.Id,
```

and the debugger tells me `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'app.Models.Contact` and `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'app.Models.Reservation`, respectively. What am I doing wrong? My `Reservation` and `Contact` models are,

```
namespace app.Models
{
    [HandleError]
    public class Reservation
    {
        //unique ID of location
        public int Id { get; set; }

        //name of location
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Ranking { get; set; }

        public bool Favorites { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and,

```
namespace app.Models
{
    [HandleError]
    public class Contact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        [Display(Name = "Contact Name ...")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        [Display(Name = "Contact Type")]
        public string ContactType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Phone:")]
        public long ContactNumber { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        [Display(Name = "Birthdate")]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've tried everything.. I think perhaps I am incorrectly using LINQ? I am at a loss here.

Comment: Your `Reservation` property is typeof `Reservation`, but you are trying to assign an `int` to it (by using `Reservation = _location.Id,`). The error would be solved by using `Reservation = _location,` but your model really should contain a `int ReservationId` navigation property (ditto for `Contact`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class ReservationDate you need to have navigation properties for Contact and Reservation tables.
Add **ContactId** and **ReservationId** properties like this

```
public class ReservationDate
    {
        //key
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ReservationId { get; set; } // this
        //location name
        [Required]
        public Reservation Reservation { get; set; }

        public int ContactId { get; set; } // this
        //contact
        [Required]
        public Contact Contact { get; set; }

        //date reserved for
        [Required]
        public DateTime ReservedDate { get; set; }

        //information from textbox
        [Required]
        public string InfoFromTextBox { get; set; }

        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        public ImagesUploaded ImageURL { get; set; }
    }
```

MVC automatically binds that **ContactID** FK to Contact table PK **ID**.

On Save you call **ContactId** instead of **Contact** object like this

```
 ContactId = _contact.Id
```